# ViewController presented slowly in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uistoryboard

I want to display next ViewController on`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and is happening as follows.

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var section = indexPath.section
        var row = indexPath.row
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tblView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
      cell.textLabel?.text = "hello"
       return cell
   }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        frequentVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("frequentVC") as? DropOffFrequentVC
        self.presentViewController(frequentVC!, animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
```

The nextViewController is presented and i dismiss the `UIViewController` as  `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)` and again the previous `UIViewController` gets called but now when i wait for sometime and try again presenting `UIViewController`, the `UIViewController` gets called very slowly but the`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called instantly. During the waiting period if i tap aroundView anywhere then instantly`UIViewController` is presented.Also, if i tapp for two times`UIViewController` is presented instantly.

**HERE IS THE PROJECT:**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6dTvD1JbkgBN0J3SkFOTDJtZlU&authuser=0

Comment: Does it help if you init the viewcontroller in `viewDidLoad` and store it as an instance variable?

Comment: nope...still the same.....

Comment: i have uploaded project ...please have a look

Answer (score 11):

I've encountered this many times.

I don't fully understand why this fixes the problem but it works.

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
```

Make sure `animated` is false and call this before you present the view controller.

My hypothesis:

The selected cell is the first responder. 
Therefore it's in charge of presenting the new view controller. 
Hence the lag. 
We can't see the actual `UITableViewCell` code because it's private but something in there is responsible for performing that action with a delay.

Note: The response above said that the lag is due to using storyboard. 
That is wrong because I'm not using storyboards and I still get the lag.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. I am also using pure code, and no storyboards etc.
Interestingly, I wasn't seeing the lag if I did either of:
1/ Pushed the VC on the navigation controller (instead of displaying modally)
2/ Presented from a UICollectionView instead of a UITableView.

So, I think it's clear that there is some bug in UITableView. I am surprised that others haven't run into this more often.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded you code.  Did not experience any lag in opening the `ViewController`. It may depend on the performance on your computer (if running in simulator like I did).

However, you should definitely make some changes to your code. Firstly look into how storyboards can be constructed. You are making a lot of UI in code now which is both harder and in your case performance wise bad. Always creating a new `UILabel` and other UI-element every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called is a bad practice.

Secondly using `seques` with storyboards also makes your life easier. Skip `presentViewController` and use `performSegueWithIdentifier` and other methods instead. A lot of the logic can be created directly in Interface builder by just dragging between the views.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/81879/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: thanks for your suggestion....but the problem is first you select a cell...and then dismiss the ViewController and then wait for some 10 seconds and again tap same cell then you will get very slow..or may you have to tap two times to present another view controller.....i have tested it in real device and also has same issues

Comment: interesting part is the more you wait the slowly view controller is presented

Comment: I would guess it's memory related. Test to run it in Profiler.

Comment: how could it be..i have very simplified code now reduced while debugging....just contains a tableview.....

Comment: Still works fine. And memory and CPU seems fine. A bit laggy sometimes if clicking a row just after dismiss but that could be related to that `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DropOff", bundle: nil)` or `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` creates new objects which could take time. Consider placing this code in `viewDidLoad` or try using segues which are built just for this. I would also just use one storyboard.

Comment: nope i dont think that it is working fine...may be you tapped twice...and trying in viewDidLoad also doenot makes that faster....which xcode are you  using?

Comment: I got the newest 6.3.1

Comment: thanks for mentioning why i should not add controls in cellforRowAtIndexPath method....it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should present your viewcontroller in main thread just like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.presentViewController(
        frequentVC!, 
        animated: true,
        completion: nil
    )
}
```